# Other cases in which an animal gets some status of its owner?

Tags: animals, teruma

An animal belonging to a kohen can eat Terumah.

Can a poor person's animal eat Maaser Ani?

If one owns an animal in Jeruslaem, may it consume Maaser Sheni?

Comment: An animal of a Jew can't work on Shabbat

Comment: The animal does not get the status of its owner. The kohein is allowed to use Terumah to feed his property.

Comment: @N.T. What about DoubleAA's example above? A Jew doesn't have the option to allow his property/animal to work on Shabbat. The animal's right to rest seems to supersede the Jew's ownership of it.

Comment: @Aaron The Jew is obligated to not use his property for work on Shabbos, as part of his observance of Shabbos. There is no such thing as an animal's right to rest.

Comment: @N.T. I believe a Jew whose animal becomes Shabbat observant cannot sell the animal to a non jew out of fear the animal will be forced to work on the Sabbath. Sounds like an animal's right to rest to me

Comment: He can't sell it because he might come to rent it to a non-Jew who will use it on Shabbos, which would violate the prohibition of having your animal work on Shabbos.

Comment: @N.T. Mechon Mamre claims animals have the right to Sabbath rest. "Under Jewish law, animals have some of the same rights as humans do.  Animals rest on Shabbat, as humans do.  We are forbidden to muzzle an ox while it is working in the field, just as we must allow human workers to eat from the produce they are harvesting."

Comment: They are incorrect re shabbos, but I'll give them the muzzling example.

Comment: @N.T. we _are_ allowed to use our property for melacha on shabbos. It's a machlokes beis shammai and beis Hillel (יש/ אין שבות בכלים), and we pasken that אין, and we may use our property to do melacha (so long as we aren't doing anything ourselves). This is why 'shabbos clocks' work. Our animals, on the other hand, have an issur melacha whether we are using them or they are acting by themselves. We actually have to _stop_ them if they are doing melacha

Comment: @Loani We are definitely not obligated to stop them if they are doing melacha on their own, e.g. cropping grass. We just can't make them work.

Comment: @N.T. sorry, I wasn't exact. We have to stop them from doing melacha on their own when it's for my benefit (and not the animal's). This is brought down in Shmiras Shabbos K'Hilchasa in full, I can quote him later, if you'd like